# Get common intent results

Tags: android

In my app, i open videos files using the following code :

```
private void openVideo() throws ActivityNotFoundException {
        Intent openIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String mime = getContentResolver().getType(contentUri);
        openIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, mime);
        openIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(openIntent);
    }
```

when the user click on the back arrow (choosed video player), i want to perform an action to move to video file to another folder "read",it's possible to get onActivityResult from it, if yes, how to get this action ?

Comment: You are welcome to use `startActivityForResult()` for any `Intent` and override `onActivityResult()`. However, just bear in mind that you cannot force an app to actually give you a result. For `ACTION_VIEW`, which is not documented to use results, I would expect `onActivtyResult()` to be called with `RESULT_CANCELED` most of the time.

Comment: i will check this and let you know

Comment: yes, if(resultCode == -1 && requestCode== readFinish) works, you deserve a +1, thank you